# How to exclude something from VsCode Search

Tags: visual-studio-code

In "Search Excludes" I have `build`, `**/*/build/**/*`, `/build`, `build/**/*`

I'm using a monorepo so a `/build` directory can appear in anywhere in the tree

Despite adding these excludes, VSCode ***still*** turns up with search results from ***any*** child `/build` directory

Please, Please, Please can someone explain how to remove these results from search. It is really slowing my machine down and is super frustrating.

Comment: is this a multi-root workspace? please show the value of your `search.exclude` setting in JSON form, and tell us which file you have placed it in (path to that file and its name).

Answer (score 0):

Exclude pattern `**/build` should be enough.
Also check the button to exclude files is switched on, otherwise filter will be ignored.

[image]